# Activate company in not all modes

Tags: company-mode

Is it possible to define in which modes (programming languages) i want to have company activated? I want to have company in all my modes but not in lisp mode.

Answer (score 6):

You can use `company-global-modes` to control that.

> (setq company-global-modes '(not lisp-mode))
>
> (global-company-mode 1)